# Validação de <input> com javascript

Tags: javascript, input, validação

Eu gostaria de fazer uma validação inline em um input.
Eu quero que caso o usuário digite algo diferente de 0 ou 1, apareça uma mensagem avisando que somente 0's e 1's são permitidos.

Eis o que eu já tentei:

```js
let valor = document.getElementById("binNumber");

valor.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  let conteudo = document.getElementById("binNumber").value
  let splited = conteudo.split("")
  for (let i = 0; i < valor.length; i++) {
    if (splited[i] != 1 || splited[i] != 0) {
      alert("erro")
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="binNumber">Binary:</label>
  <input id="binNumber">
  <label for="decNumber">Decimal</label>
  <input id="decNumber"><br>
  <button>Convert</button>
</div>
```

Não estou conseguindo solucionar isso. 
Não precisam me dar a solução de mão beijada. Agradeço se me der um direcionamento. O resto eu desenrolo!

Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 3):

o seu codigo tem pequenos erros:

1. no for vc tem que fazer a interação pelo splited e não pelo valor
2. no seu if vc tem que perguntar pelo valor em alfa nos casos "1" e "0"
3. o operador do IF deve se &&( and ).

com isso acertamos seu código, porém tem um pequeno erro de conceito, quando vc faz addEventListener ele vai executar o seu callback antes de atribuir o valor no elemento, ou seja, no primeiro clique a variável conteúdo estará vazio, e quando clicar um valor errado ele só vai validar no próximo keypress, você pode simplesmente pegar o parâmetro da function do addEventListener e perguntar para o e.key, para saber mais veja KeyboardEvent, pois é ele que vem pelo parâmetro da função, segue link da doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent
segue abaixo o código, você pode melhorar o código fazendo com que o valor inputado não entre no campo.

```
let valor = document.getElementById("binNumber");

valor.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){

    if(e.key != "1" && e.key != "0"){
      alert("erro")
    }
})
```

espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado! Testei o code, e deu super certo. 
Seu comentário foi super. Não compreendi tudo ainda, mas foi me aprofundar no que você me disse, e tentar compreender o passo-a-passo. 
Vou estudar o que você me passou, para poder compreender e conseguir fazer na próxima! 
VLW Thiago!

Comment: Tranquilo, fico feliz de ter ajudado!